# rails issue with scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I'm new to rails and messing around with scaffold. I generated a new one doing `rails g scaffold Review artist:string venue:string date:string comments:string` then ran `rake db:migrate` and it looks pretty weird, not how my professor's looked in class. I just opened it in my browser. Anyone able to explain to me why it looks like this? Sorry this is vague but not sure how to search for an answer online. Thanks

edit: I also tried connecting to localhost:3000 after starting my rails server, but it wouldn't load. any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access the file directly.

You should rather *start your rails server* and then access the page via the proper route, eg. `http://localhost:3000/reviews`

Comment: i successfully started my rails server, but when i connect to localhost:3000 nothing happens. any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to tell without more information. What happens when you try to access the server? And what does the console say when you start the server?

Comment: => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
A server is already running.

When i try to connect it just says "waiting" forever

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means that the server is listening on all interfaces, so accessing it with localhost should work.. Just to make sure, you're running the server on the same computer as the browser (I noticed that you have a bookmark for virtual box)?

Comment: yep, i'm trying to connect to it on the same server, within my virtual machine running ubuntu. doesn't work though not sure why.

Comment: If all files, the rails server and the browser are all within the virtual machine it should work. It might be some network settings in your VM that blocks connections.

Comment: Just a guess: If you have started a virtual machine (your UBUNTU-Server) your should access the rails server not using "localhost" but using the IP address of your virtual machine (enter "ifconfig" on your Ubuntu's console to get it). This only applies if your browser is in your "real" machine and your rails server on the virtual one.